# Creating Infinite horizontall scrolling ( like Ring )

Tags: javascript, css, animation, infinite-scroll

I am trying to make a container that has children Horizontally and moves from left to right
Each of those children , when it reach the end of the container => goes to the start of the container
let's imagine that it contain 4 children:

```
  0% :  ..1 | 2 | 3 | 4..    
 25% :  ..4 | 1 | 2 | 3..  
 50% :  ..3 | 4 | 1 | 2..  
 75% :  ..2 | 3 | 4 | 1..  
100% :  ..1 | 2 | 3 | 4..
```

not like the carousel, but like the ring rolling (smooth )
for infinite time

Below

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.box {
  background: orange;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 10px;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: right;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.box:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    margin-left: 000px;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is the code I have tried:

may use JavaScript.

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif the example you provide is using scss but I want it for css (and/or js)

Comment: Sass is CSS. All you have to do is to compile it to CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the soulutiion I get from [varpex](https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation) :

```css
ul {
    --d: 10s;
    /* duration */
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    /* number of visible images */
    overflow: hidden;
    mask: linear-gradient(90deg, #0000, #000 5% 95%, #0000);
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(90deg, #0000, #000 5% 95%, #0000);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul>li {
    grid-area: 1/1;
    animation: r var(--d) linear infinite;
    font-family: system-ui;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 0.5rem solid #0000;
    background: orange padding-box;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

ul>li:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: calc(-0.1428571429*var(--d));
}

ul>li:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: calc(-0.2857142857*var(--d));
}

ul>li:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: calc(-0.4285714286*var(--d));
}

ul>li:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: calc(-0.5714285714*var(--d));
}

ul>li:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: calc(-0.7142857143*var(--d));
}

ul>li:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: calc(-0.8571428571*var(--d));
}

@keyframes r {
    14.2857142857% {
        transform: translate(-100%);
    }

    14.2957142857% {
        transform: translate(600%);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">Infinite Scroll Animation</h1>
    <div class="scroller" data-speed="fast">
        <ul class="tag-list scroller__inner">
            <li >HTML</li>
            <li >CSS</li>
            <li >JS</li>
            <li >SSG</li>
            <li >webdev</li>
            <li >animation</li>
            <li >UI/UX</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

it works good and beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Check this and let me know if this works :)

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 25px auto;
    background: orange;

}

.box {  
  display: flex;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: right;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,2,3,1); //linear

}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.box:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: -515px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
     <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's close but not enough,  It stops scrolling while I am asking to not stops and goes with the same speed, just scroll like a ring or a  wheel  (bad expression ik)